# Base64 encoded bitmap returns lengthy string

Tags: java, android, encoding, bitmap, base64

I am using the following code for encoding my bitmap:

```
public static String convertBitmapToBase64String(Bitmap bitmap) {
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

    String encodedImage = null;
    try {
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos);
        byte[] byteArrayImage = baos.toByteArray();

        encodedImage = Base64
                .encodeToString(byteArrayImage, Base64.DEFAULT);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return encodedImage;
}
```

But this method returns a very long string and therefore I can't upload my image to the server.

Please help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I guess your image was very big?

Comment: What do you expect it to do? We can't magically make the image size or the size of its Base-64 representation any smaller for you.

Comment: "But this method returns a very long string" yes, that's because image files are generally large. That's just the nature of the beast. It doesn't help that you're specifying a quality value of 100...

Comment: Encoding your image to Base64 produces a string size of your image + ~30% overhead

Comment: Why not just send the image bytes rather than a Base64 string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing base64 can do for the actual size. The encoding will inevitably increase the size by a fixed percentage (about 37% IIRC).

The only thing you *can* do is make the image data smaller. You are using an unreasonable quality setting here:

```
bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos);
```

100% quality JPEG is overkill, 83-90% is more reasonable for most images. If you need lossless image quality, try PNG. JPEG isn't designed for 100% quality, the resulting file will very likely be larger than if you used a lossless image format in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

if your image is really too big you can always use Bitmap.createScaledBitmap() to resize it smaller